# Multiple inputs with duplicate value check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button to create input tags. When user click submit button I want to find inputs with duplicate values and change border to red.

*I'm not using jquery validate plugin*

**html code:**

```
<form>
<table>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="text[]" id="1"> <button class="add">add</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="check">
</form>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
// add input
var i = 2;

$('.add').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('table').append("<tr><td><input type="text" name="text[]" id="'+i+'"> <button class="add"></td></tr>");
  i++;
});

$('#submit').click(function(){
  // I do not know how to write ...
});
```

Comment: Here you go : https://jsfiddle.net/karthikvu/x55h0j8m/

Comment: _find all input same value_, you mean duplicate values?

Comment: yes duplicate ... sory my english .

Comment: @KarthikVU ups sory. </button>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you want

```
   $('#submit').click(function () {
        var valid = true;

        $.each($('input[type="text"]'), function (index1, item1) {

            $.each($('input[type="text"]').not(this), function (index2, item2) {

                if ($(item1).val() == $(item2).val()) {
                    $(item1).css("border-color", "red");
                    valid = false;
                }

            });
        });

        return valid;
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

If somebody is after this, with a lot of inputs, and is concerned with efficiency, this yields the same result (duplicates besides the first occurrence are marked):

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  var values = []; //list of different values
  $('table input:text').each(
    function() {
      if (values.indexOf(this.value) >= 0) { //if this value is already in the list, marks
        $(this).css("border-color", "red");
      } else {
        $(this).css("border-color", ""); //clears since last check
        values.push(this.value); //insert new value in the list
      }
    }
  );
});
```

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4s82L4vg/

Comment: this also could use . but Jawad Umar more useful . Thank you for your interest

Comment: this one is more efficient as it has only one loop.