# Check if pair of time inputs is not greater than or less than the succeeding time inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Noob here and I'm trying to create a javascript code wherein it checks if a time range does not overlap the succeeding time range.

I also checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439291/multiple-inputs-with-duplicate-value-check) but it only handles a single input that is repeated.

Here's my HTML:

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
  <input type="time" class="time1" name="time1[]" id="1" required>
  <input type="time" class="time2" name="time2[]" id="1" required>
  <button class="add">Add
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="check">
</form>
```

Here's the script (modified from the answer on the linked topic):

```
var i = 2;

$('.add').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('table').append('<tr><td><input type="time" class="time1"  name="time1[]" id="'+i+'" required><input type="time" class="time2"   name="time2[]" id="'+i+'" required> <button type="button"   class="add">Add</td></tr>');
  i++;
});

$('#submit').click(function () {
    var valid = true;

    $.each($(".time1"), function (index1, item1) {

        $.each($(".time1").not(this), function (index2, item2) {
            $.each($(".time2"), function (index3, item3) {

            $.each($(".time2").not(this), function (index4, item4) {
                if((($(item1).val() > $(item2).val()) && ($(item1).val() < $(item4).val()) || ($(item3).val() > $(item2).val()) && ($(item3).val() <= $(item4).val()))) {
                $(item1).css("border-color", "red");
                $(item3).css("border-color", "red");
                valid = false;
              }

            });

          });
        });
    });

    return valid;
});
```

Here's what I wanted to happen:

- The script will check whether input Time1 and Time2 does not overlap the next input values. Example: First Time1 has value of 2:00 AM and First Time2 has 3:00 AM; Second Time1 has value of 2:15 AM and Second Time2 has value of 3:00 AM; Third Time1 has value of 2:20 AM and Third Time2 has value of 3:00 AM. The script should show that the second and third time range overlaps the first time range.
- It should accept end to end times, like First Time1 has value of 2:00 AM, First Time2 has value of 3:00 AM. Second Time1 has value of 3:00 AM and Second Time2 has value of 4:00 AM. The script will not show that they are conflict :)

Sorry if this was not made clear earlier. :) Peace :D

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: A proper explanation of how this is expected to work would help. Broken code is not a good substitute for a clear and concise explanation

Comment: @charlietfl Question has been edited. Thanks for bringing it up :)

Comment: So it is all about comparing against previous row only? Or all the way up the table?

Comment: @charlietfl all the way up. :)